# Непонятный отступ в шапке сайта

Tags: html, css, bootstrap4

В шапке сайта образовался непонятный отступ при верстке сайта, помогите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**HTML**

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

.bsoft {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu {}

.menu__item {
  margin: 0 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.menu__item a {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #FFF5EE;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header">
  <video class="video" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="qsoft.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="bsoft">BSOFT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-center">
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                                    Главная
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                                    Контакты
                                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                                    Карта
                                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="dig">Первый digital-интегратор с<br> экспертизой в A.I. и Machine Learning</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так видео не на всю высоту, если хотите чтобы не было белого пространства (видео на всю высоту), то задайте:

```
.video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Пример:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2
}

.video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.bsoft {
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  color: white;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}

ul,
li {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu__item {
  margin: 0 25px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.menu__item a {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #FFF5EE;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header class="header">
  <video class="video" autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <p class="bsoft">BSOFT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-5 ml-auto">
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-center">
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                    Главная
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                    Контакты
                  </a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item">
              <a href="#">
                    Карта
                  </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p class="dig">Первый digital-интегратор с<br> экспертизой в A.I. и Machine Learning</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: И еще `body { margin: 0; }` вроде надо добавить

Comment: @DiD, это bootstrap сброс уже в стилях

Comment: а откуда прокрутка?